# Missing recommended icon file XCode 4

Tags: ios, xcode4, xcode5

I received this warning after uploading iOS application

```
Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format.
Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format.
Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format.
```

**I know how to add this icons using XCode5**, but application needs to be built in **XCode 4.6**.

*My 2 questions:*

Is there any way to add these icons in XCode 4?

Does Apple reject binaries with this warning?

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Why does the application need to built in Xcode 4.6? (Rather than built in Xcode 5 and targeting a given iOS release?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to the apple app store guidelines:

"Apps that do not use system provided items, such as buttons and icons, correctly and as described in the Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines may be rejected"

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

here is how you add icons in xcode 4.6.3
http://wpguru.co.uk/2013/09/how-to-add-ios-7-icons-in-xcode-4-6-3/

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:

A.  Add icon files to your bundle.

B.  Add icon files name to the plist.

Follow these from [Appe's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html)